# How many dictionaries/parameters for method overloadings?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I can put constraints superclass; I can put constraints on particular methods in the class; I can put extra constraints on instances for the class. Constraints are implemented as dictionary-passing. Does that mean different overloadings for a method get different numbers of dictionary arguments? Consider:

```
class Bar1 a                    -- just some classes
class Bar2 a
class Bar3 a
class Bar4 a
class Bar5 a

class (Bar1 a, Bar2 a) => Foo a  where
  foo :: Bar3 b => a -> b -> Bool             -- `b` is not in class head

instance (Bar1 (Maybe a), Bar2 (Maybe a),     -- needed from superclass
                                              -- ?but (Bar3 b) not needed (nor could it be expressed)
          Bar4 (Maybe a), Bar5 a)             -- additional instance-specific, Bar5 is for part of instance head
         => Foo (Maybe a)  where
  foo x y = True
```

As I understand from [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358056/typeclasses-without-methods-used-as-constraints-do-they-get-dictionaries), the `Bar`s not having methods doesn't matter.

So different instances of `Foo` might have different instance-specific constraints, some maybe for the whole instance head, some for only part -- like `Bar5 a` within the `Maybe a`. Does that mean that function `foo` specialised for `(Maybe a)` needs a different number of dictionaries passed, vs say for `Int`? How is that organised?

Reason for asking is [this thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2004-March/005995.html), where SPJ talks about "`bindSet` takes two `Ord` parameters at
run-time, whereas ordinary `bind` does not". (Yes quite true, but `bindSet` is not a method of a class.) I'm wondering if there's already a mechanism for a method's instances taking different numbers of dictionary parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superclasses are compiled as additional fields in the class dictionary, so the class definition:

```
class (Bar1 a, Bar2 a) => Foo a  where
  foo :: Bar3 b => a -> b -> Bool
```

compiles to the rough equivalent of an explicit dictionary data type `Foo` with three fields:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
data Foo a = C:Foo { $p1Foo :: Bar1 a
                   , $p2Foo :: Bar2 a
                   , foo :: forall b. Bar3 b -> a -> b -> Bool }
```

Note that the `foo` field accessor in this type, which also serves as the `foo` class method function, ultimately has polymorphic type:

```
foo :: Foo a -> Bar3 b -> a -> b -> Bool
```

meaning that it accepts four arguments: a `Foo a` dictionary (which contains the fields for the two superclass dictionaries `Bar1 a` and `Bar2 a`); a `Bar3 b` dictionary as a separate argument; and then `a` and `b` arguments before yielding a `Bool`.

When a polymorphic instance with constraints is defined:

```
instance (Bar1 (Maybe a), Bar2 (Maybe a),
          Bar4 (Maybe a), Bar5 a)
         => Foo (Maybe a)  where
  foo x y = True
```

this defines a "dictionary function" for constructing dictionaries of `Maybe`s.

```
$fFooMaybe :: Bar1 (Maybe a) -> Bar2 (Maybe a) 
    -> Bar 4 (Maybe a) -> Bar5 a -> Foo (Maybe a)
$fFooMaybe $dBar1 $dBar2 $dBar4 $dBar5 = C:Foo $dBar1 $dBar2 (\_ _ _ -> True)
```

Note that `foo` itself still always takes four arguments, but the field in the `C:Foo` dictionary for a concrete `Maybe X` type will be closed over the dictionaries `$dBar1`, `$dBar2`, `$dBar4`, and `$dBar5` supplied at the time the `Foo` dictionary is created by a `$fFooMaybe` call.

Sooo....

- super classes (`Bar1` and `Bar2`) are extra fields in the dictionary
- method functions (`foo`) are field accessors for the class dictionary for function-valued fields
- if there are additional class constraints (`Bar3`) on the function in the `class` declaration, these will be reflected as additional arguments to the function value of the field
- polymorphic instances (`instance Foo (Maybe a)`) are implemented as dictionary factories, and any constraints in the instance declaration (`Bar1`, `Bar2`, `Bar4`, `Bar5`) are closed over in creating the dictionary, which can copy over the super classes and use any other available in-scope constraints in constructing the necessary function values for methods

The method `foo` always takes the same number of parameters, though it will take a different number of dictionary parameters than, say, a `bar :: a -> Double` method with no additional constraints.  When instantiated at different types, additional constraint dictionaries are handled through closures when creating the dictionary for the type.

Does that make it clear?

Note that `ghc -ddump-simpl` with or without `-dsuppress-all` is very helpful for figuring out how this works under the hood.

Comment: Re the dictionary `data Foo a = C:Foo { ..., ..., foo :: Bar3 b -> a -> b -> Bool }`, the `b` (corresponding to a type 'private' to the method/not in the class head) doesn't appear on the lhs of that `data` decl. So what brings it into scope? Is it existentially quantified? (Was existential quant a thing back in 1993 when Constructor classes appeared?)

Comment: Actually, it's a rank-n type rather than an existential, and I've updated the answer to make that clear. The field accessor `foo` has type `foo :: Foo a -> Bar3 b -> a -> b -> Bool`, and after you get a `foo thing :: Bar3 b -> a -> b -> Bool`, the caller gets to choose `b`.  (If it was existential, you would have to use the `b` associated with a particular `thing`.)

Comment: With respect to the history, Haskell's original type classes as described in [this 1996 paper](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/lib/dock/HaHaJoWa1996.pdf), constrained a single type variable, and that was the *only* type variable allowed in the methods' type signatures.  See the first point in section 1.2 "Outstanding Issues".